# Is it possible to compare before and after group within different subgroups using Wilcoxon test, withing gtsummary, to produce a gtsummary table?

Tags: r

I have a at least 17 columns of variables - before and after parameters of all lipids. All separated into two groups: two different drugs.  Is it possible to build a gtsummary or any other summary table to compare those two groups?

Example:
People are put into two drugs groups Switch and continuous treatment. Two timepoints where the cholesterol is taken. I would like to compare via Wilcox test the change of the median cholesterol in the same group.
[Sample table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7384.png)

What other packages would you use to summarise tables?

Thank you.

Comment: If you can include an example of what you're looking for, that would be helpful. Yes, there are methods for comparing before and after (check out the paired t-test example in the table gallery vignette), and it's possible to compare two treatments. But I don't know exactly what you have in mind. Also, please provide example data in your post

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg Thanks for the help. I added an example. Really enjoying the gtsummary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this? The example below summarizes marker values by treatment and grade.
http://www.danieldsjoberg.com/bstfun/reference/tbl_2way_summary.html

```r
trial %>%
  tbl_2way_summary(grade, trt, marker)
```

[image]

This function is not yet in the gtsummary package, but it a proper gtsummary table and works will the related functions from the gtsummary package. Once this function matures somewhat, it will be migrated.

Comment: Thank you. Would you know any way I could summarise it? Would there be any way to do it graphically?